# Cannot open serial port via pyserial

Tags: python, usb, pyserial

I'm trying to read strings from a USB/Serial barcode scanner from a python script in Linux environment.
The device is named /dev/ttyUSB0 by the O.S.
I can read the "special file" from the shell. This command echoes every barcode I scan:

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The problem occurs when I try to open the serial device in python using pyserial. When I try it, I get an error. I suppose something fails initializing the serial port:

```
nando@nando-VirtualBox:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 313, in open
    self._update_rts_state()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 598, in _update_rts_state
    fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_RTS_str)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I get the same error using python 2.7 and python 3.5.
Any idea?

Comment: could you try running the script with sudo?

Comment: Thanks. It does not seem to be a problem of rights. I tryed as superuser with the same result. The user I'm using has read and write rights on the device, being part of the dialout group.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a known bug in certain versions of pyserial. See https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/67.
This workaround works for me: https://github.com/bewest/decoding-carelink/pull/171.